# How to filter specified text in a column using pandas and to Drop them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, twitter

This is  a column where i need to DROP text which contains and  starts with (text:"RT) , how shall i do the same in pandas any suggestions welcomed.

Example of Text in columns:

```
 text:"RT @ Bristol: From 9\/11 truthers to ... ##### This to be DROPPED on start with (text:"RT)
 text:"Bernie Sanders reveals that the family f...
 text:"TRUE TRUE TRUE"
 text:"RT @ cove_93: You know what would be funny....##### This to be DROPPED on start with 
 (text:"RT)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether a column contains or starts with text with the `str` attribute (for example, [`startswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html)):

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({ "text":["RT @ Bristol: From 9\/11 truthers to ...",
                            "Bernie Sanders reveals that the family f...",
                            "TRUE TRUE TRUE",
                            "RT @ cove_93: You know what would be funny...."]})
df = df[~df.text.str.startswith("RT")]
# df = df[~df.text.str.contains("RT")] # in case you want "contains" instead of "startswith"
```